# How to build automatically resizable image view inside a recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi guys I am still new to Android and I am trying to build a small project for test. What I am trying to do is to build a card game. For the bottom player I want to display a recycler view with all cards in his hand. I want the card images to be overlapping one on another and when a card is played to recalculate the overlapping to match parent width of the recycler view. And when the sum of card width is less than recycler views width i want them to be show without overlapping and center in the recycle view.

I just can't find out what method to use. I am using the ItemDecoration to create overlapping, but when i add overlapping match_parent doesn't work.

This is my recycler view for the game.

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <!-- Bottom Player -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/middle_section"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip"
        android:paddingRight="2dip">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/player1_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/player1_cards_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the player hand layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/player_hand"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/player_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Then i have a recycler view adapter:

```
public class PlayerHandRecyclerViewAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder> {
private ArrayList<Card> _cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
private Context _context;

public PlayerHandRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    this._context = context;
    this._cards = cards;
}

@Override
public PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.player_hand, parent, false);
    PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder holder = new PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder(v, parent);
    return holder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int width = holder.playerHandView.getWidth();
    int height = holder.playerHandView.getHeight();
    //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to populate the current row on the RecyclerView
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(_cards.get(position).getImageResourceId());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    //returns the number of elements the RecyclerView will display
    return _cards.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

// Insert a new item to the RecyclerView on a predefined position
public void insert(int position, Card card) {
    _cards.add(position, card);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

// Remove a RecyclerView item containing a specified Data object
public void remove(Card card) {
    int position = _cards.indexOf(card);
    _cards.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

}
```

Then i have a holder:

```
public class PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

RecyclerView playerHandView;
CardView cv;
ImageView imageView;

PlayerHandRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {
    super(itemView);

    String parentId = String.valueOf(parent.getId());
    int resId = parent.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(parentId, "id", parent.getContext().getPackageName());
    playerHandView = (RecyclerView) parent.findViewById(resId);
    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_hand);
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_card);
}
}
```

And this is my Item Decoration class

```
public class PlayerHandRecyclerViewDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
private final static int vertOverlap = -20;

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
    if (position != 0) {
        outRect.right = vertOverlap;
        view.invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think what you actually want is to build a LayoutManager, not an ItemDocoration.

Comment: @Karakuri yes it seems that i was doing it wrong i turned to extending the LinearLayoutManager, now the problem i have is that when i use wrap content for the card image view and overlap i see only 5 images because their initial width is more than the parent width.

Comment: public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        if (childCount > 0) {
            for (int i = 1; i < childCount; i++) {
                final View topChild = getChildAt(i);
                View previousChild = getChildAt(i - 1);
                if (previousChild != null) {
                    int offset = previousChild.getLeft() + topChild.getWidth() - 170;
                    topChild.setLeft(offset);
                }
            }
  }}

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom ImageView such as:

```
public class DynamicHeightImageView extends ImageView {

    private double mHeightRatio;

    public DynamicHeightImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public DynamicHeightImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setHeightRatio(double ratio) {
        if (ratio != mHeightRatio) {
            mHeightRatio = ratio;
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    public double getHeightRatio() {
        return mHeightRatio;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mHeightRatio > 0.0) {
            // set the image views size
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = (int) (width * mHeightRatio);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
        else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

You should call `setHeightRatio()` and pass to it the ratio which you can calculate from the given acquired Image.

In the layout file you can just replace `ImageView` with `DynamicHeightImageView` as below:

```
  <com.......DynamicHeightImageView
       />
```

The Image will now adjust based on the height of any Image.